# How to set TimeField alone 00:00:00: in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here i have mentioned My model.py in this  date field default i want to assign timezone as 00:00:00, so please help me to do this.

**Models.py**

```
class Dummy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,auto_now_add=True)
```

**Expected output  like**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "xxxx",
    "date": "2018-09-26T00:00:00Z"
}
```

**Actual Output**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "xxxx",
    "date": "2018-09-26T05:52:26.626604Z"
}
```

Comment: @MohitSolanki TIMEZONE = 'UTC'  apart form this do i want to change anything in models.py bcoz after adding TIMEZONE = 'UTC'  in setting also im getting same output like `2018-09-26T06:07:15.626452Z`

Comment: You have to manually update the existing object's timzone
`
`

Comment: @MohitSolanki manually means could u please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

From the Django documents for Field.default:

> The default value for the field. This can be a value or a callable
>   object. If callable it will be called every time a new object is
>   created.

So do this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def default_start_time():
    now = datetime.now()
    start_time = now.replace(hour=00, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    return start_time 

class Dummy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,auto_now_add=True,default=default_start_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateField` instead of `DateTimeField`.

Comment: if i use DateField it was just taking date alone but i need output in this format "date": "2018-09-26T00:00:00Z"

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't want the time component at all; it doesn't make sense to store it if you intend to zero it out in all cases.

Keep just the date, and in your serializer, use the date to instantiate a datetime.

```
from datetime import date, datetime


# Where t would normally be a date from your model...
t = date.today()
print(datetime(t.year, t.month, t.day).isoformat())
# 2018-09-26T00:00:00
```

You haven't given us information regarding how you're generating this JSON, but if you're using Django's built-in serialization, you can [write a custom encoder](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json) to handle translating dates into zero-time datetimes in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `time` part of a `datetime` object using the `.replace()` method:

```
self.date = self.date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

This will result in:

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 26, 0, 0)
```